# Updating pandas dataframe inside function called via DataFrame.groupby.apply

Tags: pandas, dataframe

This seems like a very fundamental question that would have been asked before, but I can't find an answer.

I have a dataframe. I want to do a groupby, then apply a function. I want the function to modify a column in the original dataframe.  None of these options work:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(list('abababa'), [1,2,3,4,1,2,3], [5,4,3,2,1,2,3])), 
                  columns=["ab", "x", "y"])
print(df,"\n")

### Attempt #1
def change_y(tab):
    tab.y = tab.y.min()

df.groupby(df.ab).apply(change_y)

### Attempt #2
def change_y(tab):
    tab.loc[:,"y"] = tab.y.min()

df.groupby(df.ab).apply(change_y)

### Attempt #3
def change_y(tab):
    tab.at[:,"y"] = tab.y.min()

df.groupby(df.ab).apply(change_y)

### Attempt #4
def change_y(tab):
    tab.loc[tab.index,"y"] = tab.y.min()

df.groupby(df.ab).apply(change_y)
```

However, this works:

```
### Attempt #5 -- This one works
def change_y(big_tab,tab):
    big_tab.loc[tab.index,"y"] = tab.y.min()

df.groupby(df.ab).apply(lambda tab: change_y(df,tab))
print(df,"\n")
```

So, I understand why #5 works, but I don't understand why none of 1-4 works.  Have I misunderstood groupby? I thought that it did not make a copy of the underlying dataframe, but merely constructed indices on the underlying dataframe and passed them to the function.  In that case, it seems at least one of 1-4 should work!

Does groupby in fact make a copy of the dataframe for each group?  It seems like this would be unnecessary and inefficient.

If it does make a copy, is there any other solution than #5?  I do understand that I could simply have the function create a new Series and assign it at the end:

```
df.y = df.groupby(df.ab).apply(lambda tab: tab.x = tab.y)
```

but for other reasons, that's not what I want to do in this case.

Comment: What is the goal? Why don't just do `df.y = df.x + df.y`?

Comment: I began by saying I was asking a fundamental question about how groupby works... I wasn't asking how to add two columns.   I changed the example to make it a little clearer, maybe.

Comment: According to my run, attempt #5 returns an empty data frame like the others.

Comment: Nope, @Parfait, not for me!   ab  x  y
0  a  1  1
1  b  2  2
2  a  3  1
3  b  4  2
4  a  1  1
5  b  2  2
6  a  3  1

Comment: @RexD ... please begin with an empty Python shell and run your entire posted data and see what I mean. I just re-checked!

Comment: @Parfait  is right that attempt 5 will return empty dataframe. Rex D is right too, that the original dataframe `df` has changed as desired. The key is in `big_tab` and `tab`. `big_tab` is dataframe object, `tab` is dataframegroupby object. And function #5 directly modified the original dataframe, but did nothing to groupby object. That’s why it returned empty when call `df.groupby...`

Comment: Yeah, I'm only interested in the side-effect, not the value.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that groupby does in fact make copies. I wanted to avoid this because I have a really giant dataframe.  I did come up with this solution, which is as ugly as my dataframe is giant. I have to copy only one column of the dataframe.  (It could be any column; I'm only interested in the index.)

Thanks to all who helped.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(list('abababa'), [1,2,3,4,1,2,3], [5,4,3,2,1,2,3])), 
                  columns=["ab", "x", "y"])
print(df,"\n")

def change_y(big_tab,ab_tab):
    indx = ab_tab.index
    tab = big_tab.loc[indx]  # I can do all but the update with tab.
    big_tab.loc[indx,"y"] = tab.y.min()

df.ab.groupby(df.ab).apply(lambda ab_tab: change_y(df,ab_tab))
print(df,"\n")
```